# using left outer join get get all links from the table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a multiligual website, and I want to export product's permalink in all available languages on the website. And if a Product don't have a permalink in a specific language then an empty string should be returned. My query look like.

```
SELECT Permalink
FROM Permalink P
LEFT OUTER JOIN Languages L ON L.IDLanguage = P.IDLanguage
WHERE idProduct = 11347
ORDER BY L.IDLanguage
```

But i return only the links from the product table. And if a laguage exists in Language table but have no link in Product table it will be simply omitted. But I need an empty string here is my `Language` table

```
    IDLanguage Name
_________________________
    1   English
    2   German
    12  Hungarian
    18  Slovenian
```

And here is the `Product` table

```
IDProduct IDLanguage SEOName Permalink
1         1          abc     abc.html
1         2          ölm     oelm.html
1         18         jhas    jhas.html
```

for example here the product with ID 1 has only 3 link but in Language table I have 4 languages. This means the query should still return 4 rows where IDLaguage=12 it will be empty.

Comment: Do you also have a question?

Comment: please provide table details

Comment: i guess you need FULL OUTER JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(p.Permalink, '')
FROM Languages l
LEFT JOIN dbo.Product p ON p.IDLanguage = l.IDLanguage
WHERE p.IDProduct = 1 OR p.IDProduct IS NULL
ORDER BY L.IDLanguage
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03e12/1)**

Comment: But what i need is it should still return 4 rows.

Comment: @user160820 It does return 4 rows. 3rd row is empty string

Answer (score 1):

I think RIGHT OUTER JOIN is what you need

```
SELECT Permalink
FROM Permalink P
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Languages L ON L.IDLanguage = P.IDLanguage
WHERE idProduct = 11347
ORDER BY L.IDLanguage
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need FULL OUTER JOIN

```
 SELECT Permalink
    FROM Permalink P
    Full Outer Join Languages L ON L.IDLanguage = P.IDLanguage
    WHERE idProduct = 11347
    ORDER BY L.IDLanguage
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this :

```
    SELECT ISNULL(Permalink,'')
    FROM Permalink P
    LEFT OUTER Languages L ON L.IDLanguage = P.IDLanguage
    WHERE idProduct = 11347
    ORDER BY L.IDLanguage
```